# Show error "Not Valid Win32 application" after upgraded to Heidisql v12

Tags: heidisql

Shows error  "Not Valid Win32 application" after upgraded from v11 to v12.

It shows there is problem on the plink.exe but it was fine  configured in v11.

Answer (score 0):

After upgraded to v12, Heidisql has embedded plink.exe & ssh.exe, if you have saved your own ssh executable before, you have to manually select it from the dropdown menu.

[image: Plink.exe]

Comment: You were perhaps using the 32bit version of v11, and your plink path was the 32bit version too. And now you switched to the 64 bit version probably? That error message is typical for an attempt to run a 32bit app from a 64bit app.